# Code works with breakpoints, doesn't work without

Tags: sockets, breakpoints, rtsp, rtp

I am using the Manged Media Aggregation open source https://net7mma.codeplex.com/ to implement a RtspClient that connects to VLC Rtsp server.

the problem is - when I run the code normally - I have exception says that the client can't get the Session Description from the Describe reponse (even though I can see I get it perfectly in wireshark).

When I put breakpoints - and go into the StartListening() method and to other methods in the open source code - it works fine and I get RTP stream.

**Here is the code:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    RtspClient client;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AccessWithClient();
    }

    private void AccessWithClient()
    {
        client = new RtspClient("rtsp://192.168.30.11:5544/stream",RtspClient.ClientProtocolType.Udp);
        client.OnConnect += client_OnConnect;
        client.Connect();

    }

    void client_OnConnect(RtspClient sender, object args)
    {
        // Tried to increase the timeout, but didn't solve it

        sender.Timeout = new TimeSpan(ushort.MaxValue);
        sender.SocketReadTimeout = ushort.MaxValue;
        sender.StartListening();
    }

}
```

Any thoughts about why it doesn't work?

thanks in advance

Comment: Working with breakpoints but not without is often a symptom of timing problems (the breakpoint holds things up long enough that when you continue the data has arrived)

Comment: Of course, the other way to phrase that is "the code works when I introduce a *massive* amount of delay between some of the steps compared to the pace the code can normally run at" - it sounds like you've got a timing issue of some kind.